# Can I install Delphi IDE from the InstallAware setup.exe without copy files to c:\programdata?

Tags: delphi

Delphi IDE uses InstallAware as installer in last few releases (2010, XE, XE2, XE3, XE4).  Using the normal setup.exe installation will copy a few GB of files into c:\programdata if you install all the IDE releases.

The installer consumes disk spaces quickly especially for users who use an SSD hard disk that is expensive.

Is it possible to setup the Delphi IDEs without copying files to c:\ProgramData?  Is it advisable to delete those files manually after installation too?  Uninstalling a previous version of the IDE does delete these files but as component maker, I need those IDEs for testing.

Comment: On my system, which has 3 recent Delphi installations, `C:\Programdata\Embarcadero` is 2.4MB. So, I've no idea what you are talking about. What are these GBs of files?

Comment: It might be a copy of the installation files.

Comment: @David, he's probably talking about the files in the folders with GUIDs for names (like `C:\ProgramData\{01CD0E72-1D08-4B21-84C4-C96BE90080B2}`, which has RAD Studio installer files and 484 MB of content). Or better yet this one, `{4C1A27DF-1043-4893-9757-DE2CE28C3D82}`, which is 2.3 GB itself.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see any of those. Are they left by auto updater which I happen never to use? If that's it, then just delete them. Anyway, Chau should be explicit about what these files are.

Comment: @David: I don't use the auto update functionality or web installer (they don't work properly through the proxy). IIRC, they're left behind for use when installing updates so that not everything needs to be downloaded again, but I could be wrong. (I haven't worried about drive space in quite a while.) You're right about the specificity, though.

Comment: @Ken White, only for cumulative updates. Help system updates, for instance, has never been cumulative. Also, RAD Studio 2007 had outstanding installation time due repacking 7zip archives into NTFS compressed directories (NTFS compression no longer used in modern releases)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Those folder with GUID in %ProgramData% are hidden.  May be you have to turn on viewing hidden folders/files in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer here.

> Is it advisable to delete those files manually after installation too?

Of course, official answer is NO. But you actually can delete these files at the cost of losing installer's "Repair" capability. (Repair is standard [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) feature, and InstallAway is merely yet another front-end for MSI). Also, it will render any manual restoration of particular file impossible, since files are stored in encrypted 7-zip archives on distribution medium (yet another unfriendly feature).

Unfortunately, I do not know any way to disable creation of such local copy of distribution medium.

Comment: I always have Windows compress those folders. Saves quite a bit of space, and is remarkably fast on an SSD.