# Installing Delphi XE6 creates a 3.5GB folder in c:\ProgramData - what are the penalties for its deletion?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

After installing Delphi XE6 in a VM from the web, I noticed that the disk size had gone up much more that I would have expected, even after compacting / shrinking. As well what looks like a temporary downloads directory in my user tree (with lots of *.7zip files) I found a much more obscure directory called (on my machine) {A2C8EB76-CB1E-47B5-96A7-4FD682404E92} in "C:\ProgramData". This contained a huge 3.5GB of various DLL's etc. Some of these are language files but a test of deleting the entire directory appears to have no effect on normal use of Delphi. Are there any caveats to removing this folder?

Comment: The inability to install updates without doing a full uninstall/install, the ability to do a repair, increased download time for patches/updates, etc. These are all installer-related issues; it has nothing to do with normal functionality of the IDE or compiler.

Comment: I like the ability to repair because on one of my machines I get sporadic corruptions of delphi binaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705340/can-i-install-delphi-ide-from-the-installaware-setup-exe-without-copy-files-to-c/16717979#16717979

Comment: I inadvertently deleted it for XE6  and had big problems installing update 1. I finally managed to uninstall XE6 and do a complete install of XE6 update 1, but it took me quite some time and frustration to get there. So I would rather not delete these.

Comment: Due to limited SSD space on my MacBook, I moved the contents of those folders to an external drive and only copy it back before any updates or uninstalls.

Comment: If you look at the {A2C ... folder using a utility like SequoiaView, quite a lot of it seems to be Android stuff.  Quite a lot of iOS stuff too.

Comment: @UweRaabe: That's more or less what I do too. The space in the VM is limited, but the Mac on which it runs has 3TB, so I simply copy it over to the Mac and only copy it back when needed.

Comment: @Free consulting: Yes, good point. It seems from  stackoverflow.com/questions/16705340 that I'm not the first to notice this.

Comment: @MartynA: I had no idea that SequoiaView existed. That's useful.

Comment: I think it's fairly long in the tooth - at least last time I looked; I think there are some more recent apps that do similar.

Comment: WOW! I have never noticed those files before. But looking at them I can only say that Install Aware is crap or guys at Embarcadero are to stupid to se it right. Those are instalation files which have been extracted from those 7zip files online installer downloads. And for those of you saying that these are required for updates. I don't see why. When you update your Delhi you only save some time by having some 7zip files already downladed. But based on my observation all of them always get extracted. Man I miss the days of Install Shield used for Delphi 7 which was way better and faster.

Comment: @UweRaabe: after moving the files to an external drive, you could put a [hard link or junction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006.aspx) or a [symbolic link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680.aspx) in the original folder and point it at the external drive, then you don't have to move the files back anymore.  Windows will think the files are in the original folder, but the file system will transparently access them on the external drive.

Comment: Methinks that with the accumulated wisdom demonstrated here and in the links that it would be great to have a reference blog on how to best create a slim VM hosting Delphi, especially now that more are using a Mac...